# Delete row if column contains value from to-remove-list with wildcard

Tags: excel

How do I make a wildcard so that I can find something that's not an exact match? I've tried taking out the 1, and also adding &"*" after A1 (the lookup value).

In other words, if I had **app** in the blacklist, how do I make it match **apple** so that it returns "Delete"?

```
Given sheet 2:

ColumnA
-------
apple
orange
```

You can flag the rows in sheet 1 where a value exists in sheet 2:

```
ColumnA  ColumnB
-------  --------------
pear     =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:A,1,FALSE)),"Keep","Delete")
apple    =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:A,1,FALSE)),"Keep","Delete")
cherry   =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet2!A:A,1,FALSE)),"Keep","Delete")
orange   =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,Sheet2!A:A,1,FALSE)),"Keep","Delete")
plum     =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A5,Sheet2!A:A,1,FALSE)),"Keep","Delete")
```

The resulting data looks like this:

```
ColumnA  ColumnB
-------  --------------
pear     Keep
apple    Delete
cherry   Keep
orange   Delete
plum     Keep
```

Comment: Worked for me.... `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP("*" & A1  & "*",Sheet2!A:A,1,FALSE)),"Keep","Delete")`

Answer (score 0):

Use *SEARCH Function* but you will need to enter it as *Array Formula*.
Something like:

`=IF(SUM(IFERROR(SEARCH(Sheet2!A$1:A$2,Sheet1!A1),0))>0,"Delete","Keep")`

Enter using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
This will check ***app*** or ***apple*** and all that's listed on Sheet2. 
*SEARCH Function* also accepts wildcards (eg. ?- for single character, * - for 0 or more)

**Important:** I didn't use the overkill search range `Sheet2!A:A` since it will eat up significant calculation time.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [L42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2685412/l42)'s answer:
If the number of entries in `Sheet1!A` and `Sheet2!A` are unknown, the following formula will work with a maximum number of entries in `Sheet2!A` limited to 256.

`=IF(A1<>"",IF(SUM(IFERROR(SEARCH(Sheet2!A$1:A$256,Sheet1!A1),0))+COUNTA(Sheet2!A$1:A$256)-256>0,"Delete","Keep"),"")`

Change the value **256** in all three instances above to suit your needs.